# Read & Write files synchronously using Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two pipelines in azure, lets call them **A** and **B**. **A** creates a file, if not present it will update and **B** will read it. **A** generally takes *~5 mins* to write completely. Now, sometime while **A** is already updating the file( *~5 mins is going on*), **B** reads it and gets old data.
Is there any way to make **B** wait until writing is completed. Some sort of lock mechanism on file itself ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried the following steps? If you have any questions, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a PowerShell task to wait the pipeline A's result first in pipeline B by using the REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
If the result is not "succeeded" stop the pipeline B.

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
$Urinew = "https://<Org>/<project>/_apis/build/builds/"
$Uri = $Urinew+$buildId+"?api-version=6.0"
$responseFromGet = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)}
Write-host $responseFromGet
$result= $responseFromGet.result
if ($result -ne "succeeded") {
 for($i=1; $i-le 5; $i++){
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
 Write-host "wait for pipeline A"
#Get new pipeline A's result
$responseFromGet = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)}
Write-host $responseFromGet
$result= $responseFromGet.result
} 
}
```

And you could also use the [invoke REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#invoke-rest-api) Approvals and Checks in the [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) to get the build result.